# password matching in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I used to validate my registration form by the following code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[cpassword]|md5');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required');
```

but when i browse my form it shows me an error that password doesn't match.
[codeigniter form result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCqf3.png)

Comment: try with removing "|md5"

Comment: I would use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php for hashing passwords and then create a callback for password verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php **Don't Use MD5 for passwords**

Comment: But If i wish to enter the password as hash code into my database then what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Controllers are not for database. So, please change your code to this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
```

If you want to put it as a hash into the database, you should use Models. Here is an example code:

```
 public function signup() {
    $password = $this->input->post('password', true);

    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT); // put $hash variable into your database
    ...
  }
```